# Relation in data model powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Good morning everyone, I have a problem whose cause I cannot identify and it is necessary to ask for help. When making a simple data model with two tables in PowerPivot (Excel 2016) with a one-to-many relationship, the dynamic table does not recognize the relationship and this is presented recently, since I have already made other more complex models with many relationships and they work but in the new models no. I put an example

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Relation:

[image]

PivotTable:

[image]

Comment: B1 and Item are from table2, and you are trying to use them to filter field "Name" is from Table1. However, filter flows from Table1 to Table2 only (the arrow on relations indicates the filter flow direction). It can not flow in the opposite direction (by design). As a result, there is no filtering. To fix that, you need to convert your data into a proper star schema.

Comment: Ok RADO, very thank, but how can convert the data into a proper star schema?